# Phpunit: tests not running with "Cannot open file" error

Tags: phpunit

I just installed phpunit through pear installation but I'm unable to run the tests (that were already working on another server). Can anyone tell me what's missing in my configuration?

Here is the commands output for `phpunit xxxxTest.php` and `phpunit .` :

```
$ phpunit getActTest.php 
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.8-pl0-gentoo
Content-type: text/html

PHPUnit 3.7.27 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Cannot open file &quot;getActTest.php&quot;.

$ phpunit .
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.8-pl0-gentoo
Content-type: text/html

PHPUnit 3.7.27 by Sebastian Bergmann.



Time: 0 ms, Memory: 2.00Mb

No tests executed!
$ ls
getActTest.php           getCirkwiReferencesTest.php  getListObjectTest.php  getLodgingTest.php  getPoisTest.php     getRestosTest.php  getVarsNConstTest.php
getCirkwiExportTest.php  getHomeTest.php              getLocalTest.php       getOthersTest.php   getProfileTest.php  getTeaserTest.php
```

Comment: Looks like something is wrong in the test file, based on the &quot; which is normally a web based encoding for ".  Did you take care to preserve formatting when copying from the other computer?  Also, check your file permissions after the copy.

Comment: The file was trasnfer using a GIT repository so encoding hasn't changed. I changed permission to 777 and I still got the same. In my opinion it's a PHPUnit installation problem because I had a hard time installing it on this Gentoo server. Unfortunately I still haven't solved it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your path to the file would not be correct. Please ensure that you are in the directory where the file exist. Then run run `ll` to list the file so that you are assured that you are in the correct directory. Now run `phpunit xxxxTest.php` and you'll get the result.